# Помогите с преобразованием кода из js в python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

Я написал код на js, необходимо его преобразовать в python-код, но я не знаю как работать с константами в python. Помогите пожалуйста.

js код:

```
const info = [{
    user: 'Имя_1',
    status: 'Пользователь'
},
{
    user: 'Имя_2',
    status: 'Администратор'
}]

console.log('Пользователь #1: ', info[0].user, '\nСтатус пользователя: ', info[0].status, '\n\nПользователь #2: ', info[1].user, '\nСтатус пользователя: ', info[1].status)
```

Comment: Возникает ошибка имени

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
info = [{
    'user': 'Имя_1',
    'status': 'Пользователь'
},
{
    'user': 'Имя_2',
    'status': 'Администратор'
}]

print('Пользователь #1: ', info[0]['user'], '\nСтатус пользователя: ', info[0]['status'],
      '\n\nПользователь #2: ', info[1]['user'], '\nСтатус пользователя: ', info[1]['status'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INFO = [
    {
        'user': 'Имя_1',
        'status': 'Пользователь'
    },
    {
        'user': 'Имя_2',
        'status': 'Администратор'
    }
]

print('Пользователь #1: %s\nСтатус пользователя: %s\n\nПользователь #2: %s\nСтатус пользователя: %s' % (
    INFO[0]['user'], INFO[0]['status'],
    INFO[1]['user'], INFO[1]['status']
))
```